# How to apply insets to CollapsingToolbarLayout with an image inside, so image in toolbar is drawn behind status bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout, windowinsets

I'm trying to setup fullscreen activity for Android 10 using insets. I wanted to have an image in toolbar drawn behind status bar. I've tried to use `android:fitsSystemWindows` flag in different combinations, but it doesn't work, `AppBarLayout` doesn't have correct padding and status bar slightly overlaps toolbar menu controls. So I've used convenient `WindowInsetsCompat` wrapper, [Insetter library by Chris Banes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter), to set paddings according to system window insets.

Here is my layout:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  android:id="@+id/book_activity_root"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  tools:context="com.bookcrossing.mobile.ui.bookpreview.BookActivity"
  >

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    ...
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
      app:titleEnabled="true"
      app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
      >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cover_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
        />

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        tools:title="War and Peace"
        />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_turned_in_not_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is how I set the paddings in code:

```java
    Insetter.setOnApplyInsetsListener(toolbarContainer, (view, windowInsets, initial) -> {
      view.setPadding(initial.getPaddings().getLeft(),
        windowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() + initial.getPaddings().getTop(),
        initial.getPaddings().getRight(), initial.getPaddings().getBottom());
    });

    Insetter.setOnApplyInsetsListener(cover, (view, windowInsets, initial) -> {
      ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
      params.topMargin = windowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() + initial.getMargins().getTop();
      view.setLayoutParams(params);
    });

    Insetter.setOnApplyInsetsListener(nestedScrollView, (view, windowInsets, initial) -> {
      view.setPadding(initial.getPaddings().getLeft(), initial.getPaddings().getTop(),
        initial.getPaddings().getRight(),
        windowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() + initial.getPaddings().getBottom());
    });

    Insetter.setOnApplyInsetsListener(favorite, (view, windowInsets, initialPadding) -> {
      view.setPadding(initialPadding.getPaddings().getLeft(), initialPadding.getPaddings().getTop(),
        windowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetRight() + initialPadding.getPaddings().getRight(),
        initialPadding.getPaddings().getBottom());
    });
```

I set window flags for the fullscreen mode:

```java
root.setSystemUiVisibility(
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

And this is the result pictured:

[image: Example of the incorrect padding]

Status bar is set to be transparent, blue color is from the toolbar that has top padding.

As a final result, I would like image to be drawn behind the status bar, is it possible at all?

I'm testing on the Android 10 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Your flags seem to be wrong. You set the flag for the navigation bar while you should be setting the one for the status bar.

Here is the code I use (Kotlin):

```
requireActivity().window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

to make the UI draw behind status bar without the status bar getting hidden. Then I use this extension function I use on views that should not overlap with the status bar like buttons and other controls:

```
fun View.alignBelowStatusBar() {
this.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
    val params = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    params.topMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
    view.layoutParams = params
    insets
}
```

}

So the first flags would ensure your backgrounds/images go under the status bar. The second one is to make sure that your controls are not overlayed by the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you don't need to support paddings in CoordinatorLayout manually, please see `setupForInsets` function in `CoordinatorLayout` class. To support drawing behind status bar you should set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
  android:id="@+id/book_activity_root"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  tools:context="com.bookcrossing.mobile.ui.bookpreview.BookActivity"
  >
```

And as I understand you do not need `animateLayoutChanges` here. It's responsible for animations in layout changes such as removing/adding and showing/hiding views.

Answer (score -1):

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).